# error while loading the store associated with the gridpanel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
models: [
'User'
],
stores: [
'userStore'
],
refs: [
{
ref: 'navigation',
selector: 'navigation'
},
{
ref: 'ContentPanel',
selector: 'ContentPanel'
},
{
ref: 'viewport',
selector: 'viewport'
},
{
autoCreate: true,
ref: 'myForm',
selector: 'MyForm',
xtype: 'MyForm'
},
{
autoCreate: true,
ref: 'usergrid',
selector: 'usergrid',
xtype: 'userGrid'
}
],
onSaveButtonClick(button,e,eopts){ var form1 = this.getMyForm();
if(form1.isValid())
{
var form  = form1.getForm();
user= this.getUserModel().create(
{
firstName: form.findField('firstName').getValue(),
midName: form.findField('midName').getValue(),
lastName: form.findField('lastName').getValue(),
gender: form.findField('gender').getValue(),
age: form.findField('age').getValue(),
buildingName: form.findField('buildingName').getValue(),
street: form.findField('streetName').getValue(),
country: form.findField('country').getValue(),
pinCode: form.findField('pinCode').getValue(),
state: form.findField('state').getValue()
});
debugger;
var store= this.getUserStoreStore();
store.data.add(user);
var List= this.getUsergrid();
List.getStore().load();
var contentPanel = this.getContentPanel();
contentPanel.removeAll(true);
contentPanel.add(List);
form1.close();
alert('Data stored Successfully');
}
else
{
alert('Few Datas are missing!!');
}
```

//Store 
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.userStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.userStore',
    requires: [
    'MyApp.model.User'
    ],
    constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'MyApp.model.User',
    storeId: 'userStore',
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
    type: 'json'
    }
    }
    }, cfg)]);
    }
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect for 2 reasons:

1) You should not be modifying the underlying data collection. If it's giving an error, then something else is wrong.

2) If you're loading the store, why are you adding items to it? It should already be loaded.

Comment: Actually i have a form and trying to store entered values in the store. i have a model and store assciated with this. so using getvalues() i fetched all the values of the form field and created a model instance and stored that in the store. now using the grid panel i want to display the stored values.

Comment: So put together a working test case, your code is way too lacking to say anything else about it.

Comment: i got the answer. I almost forgot to abt JSON "proxy" and "api". and i was trying reload the Gridpanel. That was unnecessary.